# callback not invoked on response

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the ui code like

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    Log Messages&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onrefresh()">Fetch New Messages</button>
</div>
```

the involved js is

```
var dt = $(document).ready(function() {
    var hostName = 'http://127.0.0.1:7101';
    ...some code

});

function onrefresh(){
    console.log("he viti");
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:7101/LogAnalyzer-RESTWebService-context-root/rest/v1/LogMessagesVORest";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.oracle.adf.action+json");  
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert('we are back');
            location.reload();
         }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));       
}
```

The callback does not happen in the onrefresh method. However, I have noticed that methods thats inside the top part involving jquery there it works fine.

Comment: Do you mean `alert()` is not called before `location.reload()` occurs?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you're using jQuery why aren't you using jQuery's AJAX methods?

Comment: What were you hoping we would be able to do about it? It isn't like we can test your server or view your developer tools. What debugging have you done? Where is `parameters` defined? Is your server getting the request? If so, what is it sending? Have you tried an `alert()` outside the `if`?

Comment: yes it works outside the ifand the call is going as well. it's jus that it doesnt invoke callback

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
request.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
      console.log(request.responseText);
   } else {
      console.warn(request.statusText, request.responseText);
   }
});
```

Comment: i get log-messages.js:184 Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Comment: @Vik you have to replace "request" with xmlhttp its just a code from documenation

Comment: What's wrong with using `onreadystatechange`? People have been using that method for years with no problem.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @Barmar probably nothing, I dont know the details of his request... might be something different, but this code works for me all the time.